# Why photons with longer wave length demonstrate more active scatter and transmit that shorter length?

Tags: spectroscopy, photochemistry, spectrophotometry

Why photons with longer wave length demonstrate more active scatter and transmit that shorter length?  This troubles me to understand why NIR and Infra-Red goes through diffused media when compared to other colors. My thought is lean to think that be the other way around. For example, X-ray are short waves but goes straight though a biological tissue.  Please, comment